# Create element from selected text

Tags: javascript, katex

I am trying to create an element from selected/highlighted text

I'm working on a WYSIWYG project and I use [KaTeX](https://katex.org/docs/api.html) to render raw math formulas to nice-looking ones.

When you select the raw formula and click "math parse" on the wysiwyg toolbar, this is what it should do :

- Get selected text (`var currentText = getSelectionText();` works for that)
- Create an element (like p, span or something else)
- Delete selected text ( `deleteSelection();` works fine )
- Render math formula in the DOM element
  ( `katex.render('currentText', new_element);` )

The second step is the one I can't seem to achieve. I don't understand how I can dynamically create a new element (this one would be a span) exactly where the selected text was and fill it with the Katex render.

My functions :

```
function getSelectionText() {
      var text = "";
      if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
      }
      return text;
    }

    function deleteSelection() {
      let selection = window.getSelection();
      selection.deleteFromDocument();
    }
```

——-————— EDIT ————————-

I came up with this :

```
var z = document.createElement('span');
        document.body.append(z);


katex.render(currentText, z);
```

This works pretty well but the element is always printed at the very bottom of my page
I want the element to be created just where the text was
Any help about that ?

Comment: Is your only question about how to position your new element? Please revise to clarify. "Any help?" isn't a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example using **[Selection.getRangeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)** and **insertNode**:

```js
// Singleton to handle caret selection
const Sel = {
  get() { return window.getSelection(); },
  range(x) { return this.get().getRangeAt(x||0); },
  ancestor() { return this.range().commonAncestorContainer; },
  text() { return this.get().toString(); },
  delete() { this.get().deleteFromDocument(); },
  insert(el, x) { this.range(x).insertNode(el); },
};

// Function to easily create elements
const NewEL = (t, p) => Object.assign(document.createElement(t), p);

// Insert SPAN at selection
document.querySelector("#insert").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const text = Sel.text();
  if (!text) return console.log("Nothing selected");
  if (Sel.ancestor().nodeType === 1) return console.log("Cannot insert");
  Sel.delete();
  Sel.insert(NewEL("span", {textContent: text, className: "math"}));
});
```

```css
.math {color: red; font-size: 2em; user-select: none;}
div {padding: 10px; border:1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
Highlight some text and click: <button id="insert">INSERT SPAN</button>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt enim deserunt officiis eum nesciunt maiores nisi voluptatum cum aperiam excepturi earum velit natus, perferendis itaque id necessitatibus. Iusto, labore repellat.
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!
However, if I highlight some text that has already been "math converted", nothing should happen. In your snippet, the code is re-executed. Is there a way to check if a class has already been applied ?

Comment: @2klm in such case you might want to check the commonAncestorContainer's  nodeType. If that helps. Edited.

Comment: @2klm you can also use CSS `user-select: none;` on your `.math`

Answer (score -1):

You should try with the `insertBefore` method : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp